# What was the last public school to desegregate in the US? And when?

Tags: united-states, racism

What was the last public school to desegregate in the United States? What was the date of completion for that schools desegregation?

Comment: Not to mention there are numerous places (particularly in the rural mountain west) where it is technically *still* segregated because no African-American family has ever lived there.

Comment: @T.E.D. - it's not "segregated" unless the rules prohibit the student of the race from attending.

Comment: @DVK - You may feel that way as a personal political matter (as is your right), but that has decidedly **not** been the position of the US Supreme Court. You may not remember (or be old enough to remember) but this was a huge fight in the 70's after the official segregation laws were repealed. See [Desegregation Busing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desegregation_busing). When people talk about "desegregation" as a historical matter, they are also talking about things like busing, not just laws.

Comment: @T.E.D. - you may have noticed that Supreme Court just agreed that judging things in 2013 by how things were in 1970 is no longer acceptable. And you were referring to "still segregated now" in your comment.

Comment: @DVK - Again, you are talking politics on a History site. If we are talking about activities associated with the history of desegregation here, that includes busing. If you want to argue with someone about what different thing it really should mean *today*, that's the domain of the Politics stack.

Comment: Is there a reason I'm unaware of that this question is being voted down?

Comment: The question was edited to specify the United States, so I think there is an exact answer for this question. I'm voting to keep this one open, unless it really is that opinionated a topic.

Comment: Define "desegregate." Black and white kids attending school on the same campus (but maybe different buildings)? Black and white kids attending school in the same building (but maybe not in the same classes)? Black and white kids attending school in the same classes (but maybe there are two separate proms)? There was a high school that held its first integrated prom in 2014.

Answer (score 8):

In 1979, the American Civil Liberties Union reopened the Brown suit, asserting that the existence of 13 racially segregated schools on either side of Topeka Boulevard violated the 1954 High Court ruling. Signing on to the suit was Linda Brown Thompson, who was 11 when her father and other black parents brought the first Brown suit.

After years of legal maneuvering, in 1993 a Federal court agreed with the A.C.L.U. Now the Topeka district is proposing to close some of the segregated schools, bus more of its 15,000 students across neighborhood lines and create magnet schools, all in the name of integration.

This information is also shown on the museum of Brown Vs Board of education which I recently visited and they have a board that say the last school was desegregated in 1994.

Source: [NYTimes](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/05/18/us/40-years-after-brown-segregation-persists.html?pagewanted=all)

Answer (score 5):

In **2016** a federal court ordered the Cleveland, Mississippi, school district to desegregate by consolidating its virtually all-black high schools with the high schools that were historically white.

> The court’s ruling will result in the immediate and effective desegregation of the district’s middle school and high school program for the first time in the district’s more than century-long history.

https://www.clarionledger.com/story/news/2016/05/16/cleveland-schools-must-desegregate/84446720/

Also referenced at https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-was-the-last-segregated-school-in-america.html (since the Clarion Ledger article can't be archived in the Wayback Machine).

Answer (score 1):

Boston Massachusetts was the Last to desegregate. Mississippi was forced to desegregate at gun point before the Schools in the North were forced to by riots. The riots in [Boston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_busing_desegregation), 1974-1976, were Worse than any in Mississippi.

Answer (score -3):

May 17th 1954 congress decided it was against some amendment and you can find the details on PBS website however from what I could find it seems that Mississippi as a whole did not want integrated schools but stuck out for freedom of choice and it's worth reading about how racist people were and it seems it eventually came about in Mississippi in 1970,

Comment: Welcome to the site, Wilma c, and thanks for trying to answer this. I think you can improve this answer by adding links to the sources you're referring to ("it's worth reading about" -- where? And where did you find the info about Mississippi?), and by being more specific ("some amendment"?).